# Setting IP_MULTICAST_IF and IPV6_MULTICAST_IF on a loopback interface

Tags: multicast, multicastsocket, setsockopt, igmp

Is setting of setsockopt with IP_MULTICAST_IF or IPV6_MULTICAST_IF valid for a loopback interface. What happens while this option setting fails and we try a sendto() on this loopback interface?

While I tried, setsockopt returns "No such device(19)" and sendto() returns error "Network is unreachable(101)". Are both the calls dependent? What are the constraints for a loopback interface created as an IGMP/MLD interface while setting IP_MULTICAST_IF/IPV6_MULTICAST_IF respectively?
What are the possible setsockopt options for a loopback interface?

Comment: Show us the code you're having a problem with.